# How can I find min/max of a column of values and add that value to all column numbers?

Tags: awk

I can't seem to find the right syntax for this awk command to find the min and max of a column of values and add (`-1*min`) value to all column values (effectively zeroing my data). Would appreciate any help! 
Thank you very much!

```
awk 'NR==1 {max=$2; min=$2} $2>=max {max=$2} $2<=min {min=$2}' <  my_data.dat | awk '{printf("%-5d%+13.5f \n", NR, $2+(-1*min))}'  > my_new_data.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go through a file twice with the same syntax you would use for multiple files and just using the same file twice.

```
awk 'NR==1 { max=$1 ; min=$1 }
     FNR==NR { if ($1>=max) max=$1 ; $1<=min?min=$1:0 ; next}
     { $2=($1-min)/(max-min) ; print }' file file
```

Detailed explanation:

`NR==1 { max=$1 ; min=$1 }` - adopt values of first record, you did this already

`FNR==NR` - `awk` with multiple input files will have a `NR` value for the overall record index number (i.e. as if all files were concatenated) and a `FNR` value for the record index number of the current file. If these match, we are processing the first file, i.e. this block is executed for the first file only.

`if ($1>=max) max=$1` - `awk`'s `if` statement syntax is `if (condition) action ; else if (condition) action ; else action`. Obviously `if else` and `else` statements are optional.

`$1<=min?min=$1:0` - and alternate `if` statement syntax: `condition?yes-action:no-action`. This requires and else-action thus the meaningless `0`. Just for your interest.

`next` - skip to the next file, so that the following block is executed for the second file only.

`$2=($1-min)/(max-min) ; print` - do a normalisation to [0,1] (you have no use for `max` in your example so I used this instead...) and print data.

Comment: 1 -79687.72398
2 -80244.28699
3 -80366.94163
4 -78051.28573
5 -75530.96294
6 -75258.26745
7 -79026.36821
8 -79416.81753
9 -79565.89216
10 -79639.14779

Comment: Yes? Take column `$2` ( instead of `$1` as I did ) and adapt your desired calculation for the output value.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It works perfectly now and I learned how to use "next" and the same file twice -- that was the trick! Thank you.